# A very simple inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, inequality, elementary-set-theory

I think the following claim is clearly correct, but I cannot prove it.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. If $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(a, b) \leq C_a$ and $f(a, b) \leq C_b$ for all $(a, b) \in A \times B$ , then $f$ is bounded above. Remark: $C_x$ is a constant that depends only on $x$.

Background of this question:
I asked the following question, and this can be solved immediately if this original question is correct. (But it was false.)
[Boundedness of a bilinear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976112/boundedness-of-a-bilinear-operator?noredirect=1#3976154)

This original question is interesting in the following sense. If $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(a, b) \leq C_a$, $f$ has a upper bound that is independent of $b \in B$. Similarly, if $f(a, b) \leq C_b$, $f$ has a upper bound that is independent of $a \in A$. Therefore, it seems to be that $f$ has a upper bound that is independent of $(a, b) \in A \times B$, namely, $f$ is bounded above. However, it was false actually.

Comment: What about a lower bound?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean bounded. I meant bounded above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even an upper bound need not exist. Take $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x$ if $x=y$ and $0$ if $x \neq y$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not correct, so find a counter example.

Hint:

> Let $f(x, x ) = x $

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a,b)=min(a,b).$ Then $f$ will be bounded by $min(C_a, C_b)$, but $f(a,a)$ will diverge to $\infty$.