# Boundedness of a bilinear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, operator-theory

Let $X, Y$ and $Z$ be Banach spaces, and $T: X \oplus Y \to Z$ be a bilinear operator, where $X \oplus Y$ denotes the direct sum of $X$ and $Y$.

Is the following true?

If $\| T(x,y) \|_Z \leq C_x\|y\|_Y$ and $\|T(x,y)\| \leq C_y \|x\|_X$, then $T$ is bounded, i.e. $\|T(x,y)\|_Z \leq C \|x\|_X \|y\|_Y$

Comment: Looks like Banach-Steinhaus

Comment: I tried to use it, but I couldn't do well.

Comment: Apply it to the set $\{T(x,\cdot)\mid x\in X,\left\lVert x\right\rVert=1\}$.

Comment: I think that you want the product space $X \times Y$ instead of the direct sum $X \oplus Y$ (in fact, if $X = Y$, $X \oplus X = X$ and it does not make sense to speak of 'bilinear operators' on this space).

Comment: $X \oplus Y$ is an external direct sum of X and Y, and $X \oplus Y = X \times Y$ as Banach space. As an external direct sum, $X \oplus X$ is not equal to $X$.

Comment: @gerw It is an additive category, so there is a natural isomorphism between the product $X\times Y$ and the coproduct $X\oplus Y$

Comment: @gerw: From context it's clear that they mean the exterior direct sum, which is the same as the product as a set. Though I agree that it looks weird to define a bilinear map on the direct sum, since it is itself a vector space, so conceptually, maps starting there should be linear, not bilinear, even if it's technically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unit $y$, let $T_y(x):=T(x,y)$. Each $T_y$ is a bounded linear operator since $$\|T_y(x)\|\le C_y\|x\|$$ Also, it is given that for each $x$, $$\|T_y(x)\|\le C_x$$ By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, it follows that $\|T_y\|\le C$, independent of $y$. But this means that for any $y$, not necessarily unit, $$\|T(x,y)\|=\|T_{y/\|y\|}(x)\|\|y\|\le C\|x\|\|y\|$$

Comment: Thank you. I understood!!

Comment: Banach-Steinhauss requires that each linear transformation in the set be bounded, so that is where you need the other inequality.

Comment: @Ruy Absolutely right! Thanks for pointing it out.